# Parse and sort html tags with beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have below HTML file, which contains `bbox` information from a PDF file:

```html
<flow>
  <block xMin="53.879997" yMin="369.965298" xMax="63.939976" yMax="380.991433">
    <line xMin="53.879997" yMin="369.965298" xMax="63.939976" yMax="380.991433">
      <word xMin="53.879997" yMin="369.965298" xMax="63.939976" yMax="380.991433">10</word>
    </line>
  </block>
</flow>
<flow>
  <block xMin="53.879997" yMin="417.965298" xMax="63.939976" yMax="428.991433">
    <line xMin="53.879997" yMin="417.965298" xMax="63.939976" yMax="428.991433">
      <word xMin="53.879997" yMin="417.965298" xMax="63.939976" yMax="428.991433">20</word>
    </line>
  </block>
</flow>
<flow>
  <block xMin="111.351361" yMin="369.965298" xMax="134.220382" yMax="380.991433">
    <line xMin="111.351361" yMin="369.965298" xMax="134.220382" yMax="380.991433">
      <word xMin="111.351361" yMin="369.965298" xMax="116.331548" yMax="380.991433">1</word>
      <word xMin="121.909358" yMin="369.965298" xMax="134.220382" yMax="380.991433">PC</word>
    </line>
  </block>
</flow>
```

Above is the bounding box areas for the words: `10 20 1 PC`

In the original document, it is written like this:

```
10 1 PC
20
```

Hence, I would like to parse above HTML file and extract *all* `<line>` tags, and then sort them all by the `yMin` value. The end output of above would then be: `10 1 PC 20` instead.

## What I've tried so far

I am not very far, as I am still learning Python. I am using BeautifulSoup4:

```py
with open("test.html", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')

    for line in soup.find_all("line", attrs={"ymin":True}):
        print(line.get('ymin'))
```

Above simply prints out each  tag and it's content.

I am unsure how I can sort the line tags though.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How is posible you get that values when you are geting 'ymin' on your code??

Comment: The code I have written does not print out the values. It prints out each <line> tag and it's content. (Like mentioned in my question)

Comment: Then get "ymin" and "text", add to some dict data estructure and search how to sort a dict by some key and you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` with `soup.find_all`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
r = [i.find_all('word') for i in sorted(soup(html, 'html.parser').find_all('line'), key=lambda x:float(x['ymin']))]
result = [i.text for b in r for i in b]
```

Output:

```
['10', '1', 'PC', '20']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.Can can define the mean value and then check with mean value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<flow>
  <block xMin="53.879997" yMin="369.965298" xMax="63.939976" yMax="380.991433">
    <line xMin="53.879997" yMin="369.965298" xMax="63.939976" yMax="380.991433">
      <word xMin="53.879997" yMin="369.965298" xMax="63.939976" yMax="380.991433">10</word>
    </line>
  </block>
</flow>
<flow>
  <block xMin="53.879997" yMin="417.965298" xMax="63.939976" yMax="428.991433">
    <line xMin="53.879997" yMin="417.965298" xMax="63.939976" yMax="428.991433">
      <word xMin="53.879997" yMin="417.965298" xMax="63.939976" yMax="428.991433">20</word>
    </line>
  </block>
</flow>
<flow>
  <block xMin="111.351361" yMin="369.965298" xMax="134.220382" yMax="380.991433">
    <line xMin="111.351361" yMin="369.965298" xMax="134.220382" yMax="380.991433">
      <word xMin="111.351361" yMin="369.965298" xMax="116.331548" yMax="380.991433">1</word>
      <word xMin="121.909358" yMin="369.965298" xMax="134.220382" yMax="380.991433">PC</word>
    </line>
  </block>
</flow>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
pricemin=soup.select_one('line[yMin]')['ymin']
list1=[]
list_last=[]
for item in soup.select('line[yMin]'):
    if float(pricemin) < float(item['ymin']):

         for w in item.select('word'):
             list_last.append(w.text)
    else:
        for w in item.select('word'):
            list1.append(w.text)

print(list1+list_last)
```

**Output**:

```
['10', '1', 'PC', '20']
```

---

To print this

```
print(' '.join(list1+list_last))
```

**Output**:

```
10 1 PC 20
```